# Does the standard give any guarantees about moving from fundamental types?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, move-semantics

Does the standard give any guarantees about moving from a fundamental data type?

```
int i = 42;
int j = std::move(i);
// what can we say about i here?
```

Reasonable options would be to keep the moved-from value untouched or set it to zero?

Obviously, the code above makes little sense by itself, but think templates.

Comment: Untouched does less work, so I would assume a reasonable implementation would behave as if it was simply copied. But I don't know what the standard actually guarantees. Interesting question.

Comment: @Tobias What do you mean by "guarantees"? In your example, `std::move` just changes the type to a rvalue reference, there is no "physical" move involved. If the left hand side doesn't have a move constructor/assignment operator, then the object is copied via its copy constructor (or simply assigned for PODs). And fundamental types for sure don't have move semantics. Is this what you are asking or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: if you think templates, don't use the value i after the move, as it could be actually moved. In this case, it's barely a copy, as native types and PODs don't have move semantics.

Comment: Just trivia, not disagreeing with the answers already here: during the development of move semantics, the possibility was considered to allow the compiler to reallocate the register holding `i` (should it be held in a register), and thus subsequent reads of `i` might yield  results other than 42.  However in the subsequent decade no proposal has emerged to allow such behavior, and no compiler vendor has yet asked for permission to do such an optimization.

Answer (score 2):

The built-in `=` operator, when used as `a = b`, has well-documented long-standing behaviour of reading `b`'s value, and storing it in `a`. There is nothing in the standard that suggests that integer assignment modifies the assignment RHS.

> **5.17 Assignment and compound assignment operators [expr.ass]**
>
> ...
>
> 2 In simple assignment (`=`), the value of the expression replaces that of the object referred to by the left operand.

Nothing is said about changing any values of any other objects, so the values of other objects must not be changed.

Overloaded custom `operator=` implementations may behave differently, and many standard library types do in fact make it behave differently, but that does not affect the guarantees provided for the language's built-in `=` operator.

Comment: However, the question was about move semantics and their use inside templated code (where std::move might be used on a POD). The assignment operator is related, but I believe the question was not about that.

Moreover, I don't believe your answer is correct in general - for example, std::auto_ptr does not follow your conclusions (even though all PODs do).

Comment: @martin_pr `std::move` never has any side effects, for any type. It merely returns its argument.

Comment: @martin_pr As for `auto_ptr`, I specifically noted that operators can be overloaded, and overloaded operators may behave differently. The question asks about fundamental types. I answered for fundamental types. (To be clear, "fundamental types" has a specific meaning, and standard library types aren't necessarily fundamental types.)

Comment: I am sorry - yes, you do say so in your answer. However, your concluding statement says that "the values of other objects must not be changed" which is a very strong statement that does not hold true for all types in general, and I was reacting mainly to that.

Comment: @martin_pr It applies everywhere the language's built-in `=` operator is used, but not where any custom `=` operator is used. I'll see if I can edit to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

PODs don't really move, they copy (or, their copy and move is the same operation, as there is nothing to really "move" in that case) - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589028/efficiently-moving-a-class-with-pods).

Comment: If I understood the comment by vsoftco (above) correctly the "move" is just a fancy way of saying "copy" and doesn't actually do anything. In this respect I do not understand your "minor optimisation" remark. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @TobiasBrüll By reading some other examples around the internets, I came to believe that the compiler might actually decide to use the same memory address to store both values in this case. But you are right, that is not true. Changing the answer now. Thanks!

Comment: @martin_pr it's possible under the as-if rule of course