# How to protect a value of a local variable after leaving scope?

Tags: c++

I wrapped a C library's `subscribe` function into a higher level C++ class' method. Inside that method the underlying C `subscribe` is called with a local `char*` variable (`char key[10]`) passed in as reference. The problem is now - which I have just figured out - since `key` is a local variable its value is not protected. I can pass its reference but that memory will be free once the scope is left. I am experiencing this `undefined` behaviour by the callback is never called - after debugging I saw that the value of the `key` is altered.

I have tried using `new char[10]` which seemed to work. But I guess it's not the way I supposed to go to.

What is the correct solution for this? **Update**: it is now fixed by replacing with `string`.

**Update**

Interface function:

```
IoT_Error_t aws_iot_mqtt_subscribe(AWS_IoT_Client *pClient, const char *pTopicName, uint16_t topicNameLen,
                               QoS qos, pApplicationHandler_t pApplicationHandler, void *pApplicationHandlerData)
```

Wrapper:

```
    std::function<void()> AWS::subscribe(const std::string &topic, std::function<void(const std::string&)> callback, QoS qos) {
  ESP_LOGI(TAG, "subscribe: %s", topic.c_str());

  std::string key("Test...");

  auto task = c_style_callback(
    [=] (AWS_IoT_Client *pClient, char *topicName, uint16_t topicNameLen, IoT_Publish_Message_Params *params) {
      std::string json;
      json.assign((char *)params->payload, (size_t)params->payloadLen);
      ESP_LOGI(TAG, "subscribe cb payload=%s", json.c_str()); // works
      ESP_LOGI(TAG, "key '%s'", key.c_str()); // undefined behaviour
      callback(key); // error, exit
      callback(json);
    }
  );

  m_error = ::aws_iot_mqtt_subscribe(
    &m_client,
    key.c_str(),
    key.length(),
    qos,
    task.get_callback<AWS_IoT_Client*, char*, uint16_t, IoT_Publish_Message_Params*>(),
    task.get_pvoid()
  );

  if (m_error != SUCCESS) {
    ESP_LOGD(TAG, "subscribe: error=%d", m_error);
    return nullptr;
  }

  return [=] () {
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "unsubscribe %s", key.c_str());  // works
    callback(key); // works
  };
} // subscribe
```

`c_style_callback` utility function:

```
template<class F>
struct c_style_callback_t {
  F f;
  template<class...Args>
  static void(*get_callback())(Args..., void*) {
    return [](Args...args, void* fptr)->void {
      (*static_cast<F*>(fptr))(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };
  }
  void* get_pvoid() {
    return std::addressof(f);
  }
};

template<class F>
c_style_callback_t< std::decay_t<F> >
c_style_callback( F&& f ) { return {std::forward<F>(f)}; }
```

Main task where the `subscribe` wrapper is being called:

```
{
...
aws->subscribe(
  topic,
  [&] (const std::string &json) -> void {
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "got json: %s", json.c_str());
  }
);
...
}
```

**Update #2**

The callback lambda inside the `c_style_callback` does not access to the correct values of `callback` and `key`. How to protect these 2 from getting overwritten? "Wrapping" them inside a `unique_ptr`? Return `task` to the caller for reference? Also, the return value of the helper `get_pvoid()` points the user data which is the lambda function, maybe that should be protected?

Comment: In C++ you do this by passing in `const` data. Please don't tag as C and C++ if you want a C++ answer.

Comment: Tag C has been removed.

Comment: Most likely `char key[10]` is fine.  Check the documentation on the `subscribe` function to see what kind of pointer it expects.

Comment: If the value is going to be damaged, make a copy.

Comment: please post the interface function's declaration and a sample of code with which you're trying to call it.

Comment: @RichardHodges Thanks, ok.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, for situations like this, `std::string` (or string_view) is usually your first choice.

Comment: @JerryCoffin string_view only useful is part of the c interface contains a size parameter. string_views don't always have a trailing zero.

Comment: @RichardHodges: While more or less true, I'm not sure how that's particularly relevant. I haven't looked through all the code that's been added, but at least as originally posted, I don't recall seeing enough information to be sure whether a string_view would work or not.

Comment: One note on your code: Whenever you are using array new, you are very surely doing something wrong. Use `std::vector` instead. Even using plain new is usually a sign of bad code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll bear in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this is to allocate the memory on the heap (`new`, `malloc`). You have several choices:

1. **Preferred choice:** If you `new` the memory, you can wrap the pointer into a **`std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`**, and safely pass that around. When the last instance goes out of scope the memory is automatically released. Direct access to the pointer can be gained with `get()`. You must ensure that noone else releases your memory!
2. Use a RAII(Resource Acquisition Is Initialization)-wrapper type, which does `malloc` and `free`, or `new` and `delete`. In this case you allocate the memory via the constructor, and release it via the destructor, while you pass the raw pointer to the C-interface. Has the downside that you have to implement copy/move-semantics to make sure you don't release twice, and that you correctly keep track of all copies that store this pointer. Due to the complexity this involves, I would advise you use `unique/shared_ptr`, if you can by any means. It is also possible to pass a custom deleter to the `shared_ptr`, so you can also use it with `free` as a deleter.
3. You could use the raw pointer from new, but the you have to ensure to delete it exactly once.

Comment: Naked `new`/`delete` should be avoided. Maybe mention `std::make_unique`/`std::make_shared`..

Comment: @midor Which one you think is best for this problem? `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`? Can you please add some simple code of using one of these?

Comment: @haxpanel General rule of thumb: Start with the most restrictive, `std::unique_ptr`, and weaken the restrictions, `std::shared_ptr` in this case, only if forced to. The hint is in the name: `shared_ptr` should be used if the object is shared. If multiple other objects have an ownership stake in the object--the object must not be destroyed so long as any of the holders are using it--only then should you use a `shared_ptr`. [A few words worth reading on the concept of Ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024982/what-is-ownership-of-resources-or-pointers).

Comment: if you have to make the choice as a function return value, I would go with the `unique_ptr`, because that can be implicitly converted to a `shared_ptr`.