# Why is concatenating two linked lists by assigning pointers wrong?

Tags: c++, linked-list

So our lecturer just showed us how to concatenate two linked list but then went on and showed us and example that would be wrong if implemented,I don't seem to quite understand why it won't work as good,since it wasn't explained.What would be the problem if I concatenate two linked lists this way:

```
template <typename T>
void LList<T>::concat(LList<T> const & list) {
    end->next = list.start;
    end = list.end;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The approach used in the question is wrong because it incorrectly shares [Ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024982/what-is-ownership-of-resources-or-pointers) of the transferred nodes.

`list` owns its nodes. It maintains and ultimately releases them. By giving pointers to nodes owned by `list` to the receiving linked list, you will now have two linked lists referring to and trying to own the same set of nodes.  If you later modify `list`, you will modify the receiver and potentially leave it in an inconsistent state (`end` may no longer be correct, for example). If you later destroy `list`, the receiver is left pointing to invalid memory after `list` destroys its nodes. Likewise `list` is left in a precarious state by modifying or destroying the receiver.

This is somewhat related to [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), and it's the copy constructor required by Rule of Three that I'd take advantage of to get out of this mess. I'd pass `list` in by value rather than as a reference so that it is correctly duplicated and then move its list of nodes, copies of the nodes owned by the source list, into the receiving linked list. You can then clean up `list` so that it is safe to destroy and leave it to die when it goes out of scope. This approach may be a little slow, but it's very nearly foolproof. See the [Copy and Swap Idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) for a nearly identical trick being applied to the assignment operator.

Comment: Ohh I see that makes more sense now,thanks for the help :)

Comment: Alternatively, change it to `void LList<T>::concat(LList<T>& list) `, and make sure that `list` no longer owns the nodes now that you've stolen them. You're the programmer, you can decide how the operation should work, but you should be consistent in your choices.