# Lab 3.10.2 Dynamic data – how to obtain it and how to get rid of it

Tags: c++

So, the problem presented is,

Look at the code below – it's a skeleton of a program operating on the dynamic collection of data.

The idea is to use a structure
containing two fields: the first stores the number of elements in collections, and the second is the actualcollection (a dynamically
allocated vector of ints).

As you can see, the collection is filled with the required amount of pseudo-random data.

Unfortunately, the program requires completion, as the most important function, intended to add elements to the collection, is still empty.

Here's what we expect from the function:

if the collection is empty, it should allocate a one-element vector and store a new value in it;

if the collection is not empty, it should allocate a new vector with a length greater by one than the current vector, then copy all
elements from the old vector to the new one, append a new value to the new vector and finally free up the old vector.

I'm not hoping for the solution or anything but a pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

I've been tinkering at it for a while, and managed to get it to at least make array larger by one, but it only ever seems to copy over the location of the first value.

My code is just the stuff under AddToCollection, by the by.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
struct Collection {
int elno;
int *elements;
};
void AddToCollection(Collection &col, int element) {
// Insert your code here


if(col.elements != NULL) {
    col.elno = sizeof(col.elements);
    ++col.elno;
    int *jeffry = new int[col.elno + 1];
    jeffry[col.elno] = element;
    for (int f = 0; f < (col.elno - 1); f++) {
        jeffry[f] = col.elements[f];
    }


    col.elements = jeffry;
}
if(col.elements == NULL){
    col.elements =new int[element];

    }

}

void PrintCollection(Collection col) {
cout << "[ ";
for(int i = 0; i < col.elno; i++)
    cout << col.elements[i] << " ";
cout << "]" << endl;
}

int main(void) {
Collection collection = { 0, NULL };
int elems;
cout << "How many elements? ";
cin >> elems;
srand(time(NULL));
for(int i = 0; i < elems; i++)
    AddToCollection(collection, rand() % 100 + 1);
PrintCollection(collection);
delete[] collection.elements;
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Why are you using manual memory management when the description says to use a vector?

Comment: Saw the title and expected a assignment dump. Good to see code. I'm going to go over the code in a second, but the title is not very descriptive. It says almost nothing about what your problem is. The question itslef says very little about what the problem is. This means I may dive into your code and find stuff you are not looking for. I recommend being explicit  when asking a question.

Comment: That's fair, I'll edit it a bit. Thanks!

Comment: Discuss `col.elements = new int[element];` with [your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Explain to it what this line does and what you want it to do.

Comment: Unrelated: Rather than `delete[] collection.elements;` in `main`, add a destructor to `Collection` to do the clean-up. That's what destructors are for. But... As soon as you do this you have to worry about the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). You can avoid this for now, but you might as well learn it now because you can't write good, non-trivial C++ code without a good handle on the Rule of Three [and its friends](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: OK. Now that I've loaded the updated question, it's not so unrelated anymore. Here's another link: [RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii). In general an object should [own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024982/what-is-ownership-of-resources-or-pointers) and manage all of its resources. Do it right and the object hides all of its internal complexities. Use constructors and destructors and move most of your functions into Collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting there, but what you are not quite getting is (1) `col.elno = sizeof(col.elements);` is invariant and is actually equivalent to `col.elno = sizeof(a_pointer);` (which is not what you want), and (2) there are two mutually-exclusive conditions you must handle within `AddToCollection`.

1. `col.elements` is not yet allocated, where you simply allocate an array of `1` and set the first element to `element` while incrementing `col.elno`; and
2. `col.elements` has been previously allocated and you must essentially `realloc (col.elements, ...)` using `new` and `delete[]`.

Since you must copy your old `col.elements` to the new block of memory you allocate in the 2nd case above, it helps to include `<cstring>` to provide `memcpy` to help in that regard. The approach is simple. Create a new integer array of `col.elno + 1` elements, then `memcpy` your existing `col.elements` to your new block before you `delete[] col.elements`. Then just assign your new block of memory to `col.elements` before setting `col.elements[col.elno++] = element;`.

You could do:

```
void AddToCollection (Collection &col, int element)
{
    if (!col.elements)
        col.elements = new int[1];
    else {
        int *tmp = new int[col.elno + 1];
        memcpy (tmp, col.elements, col.elno * sizeof *col.elements);
        delete[] col.elements;
        col.elements = tmp;
    }
    col.elements[col.elno++] = element;
}
```

**note:** you should always validate your memory use by using a memory error checking program such as `valgrind` for Linux. (there are similar checkers for each OS).

Your program then becomes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct Collection {
    int elno;
    int *elements;
};

void AddToCollection (Collection &col, int element)
{
    if (!col.elements)
        col.elements = new int[1];
    else {
        int *tmp = new int[col.elno + 1];
        memcpy (tmp, col.elements, col.elno * sizeof *col.elements);
        delete[] col.elements;
        col.elements = tmp;
    }
    col.elements[col.elno++] = element;
}

void PrintCollection(Collection col) {
    cout << "[ ";
    for(int i = 0; i < col.elno; i++)
        cout << col.elements[i] << " ";
    cout << "]" << endl;
}

int main(void) {

    Collection collection = { 0, NULL };
    int elems;

    cout << "How many elements? ";
    cin >> elems;
    srand (time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < elems; i++)
        AddToCollection (collection, rand() % 100 + 1);

    PrintCollection(collection);

    delete[] collection.elements;

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/dyncolelements
How many elements? 10
[ 1 21 26 24 57 26 99 86 12 23 ]
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

```
$ valgrind ./bin/dyncolelements
==11375== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==11375== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==11375== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==11375== Command: ./bin/dyncolelements
==11375==
How many elements? 10
[ 14 32 40 65 10 4 38 72 64 83 ]
==11375==
==11375== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11375==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11375==   total heap usage: 11 allocs, 11 frees, 72,924 bytes allocated
==11375==
==11375== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==11375==
==11375== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11375== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always verify all heap blocks were freed and there are no leaks are possible and there are no errors reported.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Yeah, I could figure out that I was getting the address for something, but couldn't figure out what in particular was wrong. The !col.elements was really neat, I don't consider the ! operator as much as I probably should. Very much appreciated.

Comment: Glad it helped. It is a good exercise to understand the use of `new/delete` and `malloc/calloc/realloc` as you will see it in a lot of the older code-base. But going forward, the C++ containers such as `vector, string, map, etc..` provide auto memory handling and should be used instead (much less error prone).