# how to pass a Unique Pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class Container, having a data member.

```
std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Sum_Function> > Functions;
```

This is how i add value to the vector.

MaxSize is the child of Sum_Function.

```
void WavefrontRenderer::AddMaxSize()
 {
     Container cont;
     std::unique_ptr<Sum_Function> ptrMaxSize = std::make_unique<SumMaxSize>();
     cont.AddFunction(ptrMaxSize);
}
```

this is the defination for Function in the Container class.

```
void Container::AddFunction(std::unique_ptr<Sum_Function> &func)
 {
   std::unique_ptr< Sum_Function > function(std::move(func));
   this->Functions.push_back(function);
 }
```

Is this the correct way to add Unique pointer to a vector.

Comment: Why did you do a function(std::move(func))?

Comment: What does bool return?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<Sum_Function> ptrMaxSize = std::make_unique<SumMaxSize>();` does this compile?

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo yes it does compile as SumMaxSize is child of Sum_Function.

Comment: @Gyapti jain typo error updated it.

Comment: You need to make a [mcve] to not confuse us with stuff like that :-)

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57702591/casting-of-smart-pointers check this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To move an existing `Sum_Function` subclass object pointer into `Functions` you can do like this:

```
void AddFunction(std::unique_ptr<Sum_Function>& func) {
    Functions.emplace_back(std::move(func));
}
...
Container c;
auto f = std::make_unique<SumMaxSize>();
c.AddFunction(f);
```

... or like this, which requires the argument to be an rvalue reference, which in turn makes the pointer-stealing more obvious:

```
void AddFunction(std::unique_ptr<Sum_Function>&& func) {
    Functions.emplace_back(std::move(func));
}
...
Container c;
auto f = std::make_unique<SumMaxSize>();
// c.AddFunction(f);                           // Error, f is an lvalue
c.AddFunction(std::move(f));                   // OK, xvalue
c.AddFunction(std::make_unique<SumMaxSize>()); // OK, prvalue
```

You could also provide a convenience member function in `Container` for creating it directly in the vector without the middle step:

```
template<typename T, class... Args>
void emplace_back(Args&&... args) {
    Functions.emplace_back(std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

And instead of doing `make_unique` first and calling `AddFunction`, just:

```
Container c;
c.emplace_back<SumMaxSize>();
```

The perfect forwarding in the `emplace_back` function template above will also make the in-place construction to work for subclasses with constructors that takes arguments:

```
struct BiasedSumFunc : Sum_Function {
    BiasedSumFunc(int bias) : bias_(bias) {}
private:
    int bias_;
};
... 
Container c;
c.emplace_back<BiasedSumFunc>( -5 );
```

Comment: i have no arguments to pass can i i do this.

Comment: template<typename T >
void Container::AddFunction()
{
 this->Functions.emplace_back(std::make_unique<T>());
}

Comment: @sam Sure, if you'd like to make sure that only default constructed `Sum_Function` sub-classes are placed in the vector via `AddFunction`, but that puts restrictions on the users. If someone inherits from `Sum_Function` and adds a constructor that takes arguments, the user would not be able to use that `AddFunction` to construct his/her sub-class object in-place. Instead, the user would have to first `make_unique<SubClass>(argument)` and then call an overload of `AddFunction` that steals the pointer (like my second alternative above).

Answer (score 0):

A `unique_ptr` can't be copied, only moved. So when calling `push_back()`, you need to use the overload that moves from an rvalue, not the one that copies from an lvalue:

```cpp
void Container::AddFunction(std::unique_ptr<Sum_Function> &func)
{
    std::unique_ptr< Sum_Function > function(std::move(func));
    this->Functions.push_back(std::move(function));
}
```

Which makes the local `function` variable redundant, so you can remove it:

```cpp
void Container::AddFunction(std::unique_ptr<Sum_Function> &func)
{
    this->Functions.push_back(std::move(func));
}
```