# c++ dynamic array of pointers - when i need to use it?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand when I need to allocate an array of an object that each  pointer to some object for example array of Student that point to Student:

```
Student** db = new Student*[size]
```

when do I need to use it? I know that is a general question, but I'm trying to solve some Exam that combines inheritance, and in some class, one of the data member they declare it as I said above. 
in my solution i wrote:

```
Student * db = new Student[size];
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR version:

Use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Student>> db`.

## Explanation

```
Student** db = new Student*[size]
```

could be used to represent an array of classes derived from `Student`.

eg:

```cpp
Student** db = new Student*[size];
db[0] = new Grad_Student();
db[1] = new Coop_Student();
db[2] = new Elementary_Student();
```

If you elect the second option

```cpp
Student * db = new Student[size];
db[0] = Grad_Student();
db[1] = Coop_Student();
db[2] = Elementary_Student();
```

you save a lot of pesky manual memory management by directly holding `Students` rather than pointers to `Student`s, but [Object Slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) will turn the derived `Student`s into plain old `Student`s. A box sized and shaped to fit a `Student` can only store a `Student`, so all of the additional features of, for example, the `Grad_Student` assigned to `db[0]` will be lost. Only by storing a reference to the `Grad_Student` can the `Grad_Student`'s extensions be preserved. You just have to remember that the `Grad_Student` is actually stored somewhere else.

Sounds good right? It is until you look at all of the dynamic allocations you have to make sure are cleaned up.  Memory management is one of the hardest things to get right in C++, and one of the best ways to manage memory management is through [Resource Allocation Is Initialization or RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii). `std::vector` and `std::unique_ptr` are fabulous examples of RAII in action.

`vector` is a dynamic array all nicely wrapped up inside a class that handles virtually every aspect of list management right down to adding, removing, resizing, and making sure everything gets cleaned up. `unique_ptr` is a [Smart Pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) that ensures exactly one [owner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024982/what-is-ownership-of-resources-or-pointers) of a resource, and this owner will clean up the resource when it is destroyed. The result, `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Student>>` will allow you to add, remove, access, and move any `Student`s without any direct intervention. This allows you to write simpler code. Simpler code is less likely to have bugs. Fewer bugs means more leisure time and happier clients. Everybody wins.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you already have a collection, for example a linked list of Students which is in order by Student ID.  You want to sort them by Student last name.  Instead of changing your linked list, or messing up its order, you just allocate an array of pointers and sort that.  Your original list remains intact but you can do fast binary searches by last name using your array.