# How can I delete heap object pointers in the destructor of (inter-dependant) classes and don't encounter problems when I create stack objects?

Tags: c++, oop

I have some classes that accept pointers to instances of other classes as arguments and stores them in their private members. If in the client code I create objects of all types on the stack, when the main returns they auto destruct and program works just fine. But if I create the same objects on the heap, I should delete the pointers to those objects in the destructors of the class(es) and again program executes fine. However, if I keep the changes and create objects on the stack again, there is memory corruption because of double delete. How can I make my classes destroy the pointers in either case without modifying the main client code?

Comment: `I should delete the pointers to those objects in the destructors of the class(es)` no, only creator of the object should delete it

Comment: in general - don't use raw pointers in c++, use smart ones, like std::shared_ptr

Comment: Helpful reading; [What is ownership of resources or pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024982/what-is-ownership-of-resources-or-pointers)