# How to free a vector?

Tags: c++, class, methods

In my class I wrote

```
class Game {
private:
    mtm::Dimensions dimensions;
    std::vector<Character*> board;


public:
    explicit Game(int height, int width):dimensions(height,width), board(height*width){
    }

    ~Game() {}
};
```

But how should I free my vector, I think it leaks memory if I leave the d'tor empty.

Comment: That depends on where the `Character*` comes from. If it's allocated with `new`, then yes, you have to `delete` it.

Comment: the vector will be destroyed automatically (because it is a member) and also the vector takes care of destroying its elements, but I suppose the leak is the `Character` objects that the elements point to. Do you really need pointers in the vector?

Comment: If they don't have to be pointers, then you can just use `std::vector<Character>`. If they do have to be, you can use `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Character>>` … If you want to stay as is, then in `Game`'s destructor, you have to loop over its contents, and delete each `Character` (assuming `Game` 'owns' them)

Comment: Let your `vector` hold smart pointers - `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` rather than raw pointers, then the vector elements will automatically die when the `vector` dies. Or just hold objects in the vector rather than pointers to objects. Then cleanup is also automatic.

Comment: It's basically impossible to answer this question without seeing where the pointers come from, and why you are using pointers at all, instead of objects.

Comment: Before you so anything you need to [determine who owns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024982/what-is-ownership-of-resources-or-pointers) the allocations being pointed at by the elements of `board`.

Comment: you already have good answers, but I think none of them mentions that in your current code there is no memory leak. Acutally no `Character` is created and all memory allocated in your code is automatically freed

Answer (score 4):

If `Game` is not the owner it must not free the memory. The owner has to clean up.

If `Game` is the owner it can delete all elements in the destructor

```
~Game() {
    for (auto &character : board) {
        delete character;
    }
}
```

The better way is to use smart pointers and remove the destructor

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Character>> board;
```

You should try to follow the [rule of 0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `Game` owns the objects, then your `Game` destructor would need to free up the memory. Presumably, the `Character`s are allocated with `new`. The below will delete all the `Character`s in the `board`, then the class variables (like the `vector`) will automatically be freed afterward.

```
~Game() {
   for ( Character *character : board )
      delete character;
}
```

Unless this is for an exercise with pointers, it's generally recommended not to use bare-pointers, and instead use a smart pointer, such as `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`.

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Character>> board;
```

In this case, there will be no leak, since the `Character`s will automatically be freed once no one points to them anymore.

Use of `shared_ptr` vs `unique_ptr` is dependent on what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

The vector is a member variable. Member variables, like all sub objects are automatically destroyed when the super object is destroyed. The implicitly generated destructor does the right thing for vector.

Note that the vector contains pointers. If those pointers point to dynamically allocated objects, and are the only pointers to those objects, then those objects would have to be deleted, or else they would leak. If something else owns the pointed objects, then there is nothing that needs to be done in this destructor.

An example where the implicit destructor is correct. I pretend that the member is public for this example:

```
{
    Character c;
    Game g;
    g.board.push_back(&c);
} // no leaks
```

Avoid owning bare pointers. Prefer to use RAII containers or smart pointers if you need ownership of dynamic objects.

Answer (score -3):

the vector destructor won't leak memory you should write destructors for the types used in the vector. Also I wouldn't recommend a pointer to something which dosen't destruct itself.

I think what you are looking for are smart pointers.