# aggregation - how to elegantly free the memory allocated for the object ? - details inside

Tags: c++, memory-management, aggregation

(C++)
I find it a bit troublesome to managing elegantly memory in the following scenario:

I have a class named A, that has a member of class B.
class B has pointer member to class C :

```
class C{}

class B{
 C* c;
}

class A{
 B b;
}
```

**in class A's constructor, I initialized class B by passing it a pointer to object of class C I just created.**

now, in the destructor of A, I want to free the object of class C I passed to B.

all of the options I know to do that just look for me not very elegant:

make C public in B so I can just do: "delete(b.c);"
create a getter of the c pointer inside B and then do: "delete(b.Getblabla())"
save the pointer I passed as a member of A and then release it: "delete(pointer_to_c)"

do you have some elegant offers?

**edit:
hey some clarifications, the reason why A allocates C and passing it to B is that C is an interface and I want B to be initialized with different implementations of C depends in the situation.**

Comment: Its not 'A's job to clean up 'B's resources.

Comment: I agree with @tkausl ! Free the memory in B's destructor ^^

Comment: Handy reading: [What is ownership of resources or pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024982/what-is-ownership-of-resources-or-pointers)

Comment: The design goal of making `A` responsible for `B`'s internal resources is inherently inelegant. You can't practically make it elegant. `B` should be responsible for it's own internals.

Comment: Why does `A` create the `C`? It may be better if `B`'s constructor picks up that responsibility. That way `A` gets to remain blissfully ignorant of what's going in in `B`. Yay encapsulation.

Comment: hey, i edited the post with clarification on why i need A to create C. I'd be glad to hear your opinion

Answer (score 3):

`A` contains an object of type `B`. So `A` should not have to do any cleanup itself. Instead, `B` should clean up the memory, since that is the class that contains an owning pointer.

```
class B {
  C *c;
  public:
    B(C *c) : c(c) {} 
    ~B() { delete c; }
};
```

When the destructor of `A` runs, the destructor of `B` will be run, which will clean up the memory. Of course, now you will need to define the copy and move operations for `B` as well. See [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) for more details.

Instead, `B` could be written like this:

```
class B {
  std::unique_ptr<C> c;
};
```

and now you don't have to do any cleanup yourself, since `unique_ptr` will take care of that.

Comment: hey, i edited the post with clarification on why i need A to create C. I'd be glad to hear your opinion

Comment: The answer is still applicable. Try it out, and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and arguably cleanest is probably to just keep the C instance in A in the first place:

```
class A {
    CImplementation c;
    B b;
public:
    A() : b( &c ) {}
};
```

If you truly needed it to be dynamically allocated for some reason, use an `unique_ptr< C >` member and allocate the appropriate C derivative in A's initializer list.