# When should you use pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, memory

I get that you need pointers for handling something that grows and shrinks dynamically. In instances where that isn't the case, to my understanding, you use pointers when: your object is too big to be stored on the stack, or when you would like a function to modify data outside of its scope (why not just use references here?). Is this line of thinking correct?

Other uses I can think of are for polymorphism and forward declarations. The other example people always give is pointer arithmetic and handling array indices, but then why not just use C++ iterators which just wrap pointers... Are there any other (common) cases? I used to think that pointers were useful as they allowed for objects to be passed around without the need for a full copy to be made, but surely move semantics allow you to accomplish that without the need for handling pointers?

Overall, I feel like I am using too many unnecessary pointers in my codebase and I would really appreciate it if someone could definitively clear things up.

Comment: In short: Almost never. You ain't gonna need them. You can always either use [standard containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) or [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).

Comment: There are exceptions, such as writing to hardware devices.  Some hardware devices are mapped to addresses.  The way to access them is to load a pointer with the address of the hardware device, then write to the h/w device via the pointer.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Although that's usually only the case in embedded systems or driver programming nowadays; this isn't the '80s, where game programmers interacted with the hardware directly (and when they screwed up, crashed the whole computer).

Comment: You should use *raw* pointers when there are no other solutions available (including redesigning the program).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Pointers are ok. Use them. Don't use OWNING raw pointers though.

Comment: You will find cases where raw, [non-owning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024982/what-is-ownership-of-resources-or-pointers) pointers are the right solution. For example try to assign a class with a reference member. Pain in the <expletive deleted>. Of course then you gotta wonder, "Why do I have a reference member?"

Comment: @Swordfish We can agree to disagree. Can you tell at least a single situation (besides what _@Thomas Mathews_ mentioned) where you need to use them in c++? Even for non owning we are better off with `std::weak_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @user4581301 As I said above. Please tell t least a single one? What you said in the end: _"Why do you need to have a reference member?"_.