# Pointer to a std::vector object(s)

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers, stdvector

I need to do the following:

```
 std::vector<std::string> A; 
 std::vector<std::string> B;
 
 ==> pointer_to_vector<std::string> ptr;

//Some Code
ptr = A; //ptr points to object A

//Some More Code
ptr = B; // //ptr points to object B
```

During the program, `ptr` needs to refer to both `A` and `B` at different times. How would it be implemented and considering that `std::vector` makes reallocations, how to use smart pointers here?

Comment: `std::vector<std::string>*` ?

Comment: "how to use smart pointers here?" why do you need a smart pointer here?

Comment: There is no need for a smart pointer here, a plain raw pointer will suffice.

Comment: Smart pointers manage [ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024982/what-is-ownership-of-resources-or-pointers). In the case of an Automatic variable, ownership is already managed. When the variable goes out of scope, it's taken care of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define a pointer to a vector the same way you define a pointer to any other type - using `*` in the pointer declaration, and the `&` address-of operator to get the memory address of a variable to assign to the pointer, eg:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> A; 
std::vector<std::string> B;
 
std::vector<std::string> *ptr;

//Some Code
ptr = &A; //ptr points to object A

//Some More Code
ptr = &B; // //ptr points to object B
```

Or, use [`std::addressof()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof), if any objects overload `operator&` for their own purposes (which `std::vector` does not), eg:

```cpp
//Some Code
ptr = std::addressof(A); //ptr points to object A

//Some More Code
ptr = std::addressof(B); // //ptr points to object B
```