# keep vector elements of struct type even after deleting the struct elements

Tags: c++, vector

I have the following code

```
    struct A
    {
         char* str;
         char* str1; 
    
    };
    A a;
    main(){
    std::vector<A> vect;
    string b = "Data structures using c and c++"
    a.str = new char[10*sizeof(char*)];
    a.str1 = new char[15*sizeof(char*)];
    strcpy(a.str,b.c_str());
    vect.push_back(a);
    
    delete a.str;
    
    }
```

After deleting a.str the value of vect is also getting erased. My question is is there any means so that the value retained in vect even after delete a.str

Comment: A proper class with a proper copy constructor.

Comment: Why not have `std::string`s in the struct instead?

Comment: Use a `std::string` instead of a `char*` and it will handle the copying (and deleting) for you

Comment: Why are you using `new[]` to begin with?  It looks like you're looking for a problem to a solution, and that solution is to use `std::string`, example: `struct A { std::string str; std:string str1; };`.

Comment: Generalizing this past "Just use `std::string`",  you need to establish [ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024982/what-is-ownership-of-resources-or-pointers) of the resource. If the two objects will share the resource, use `std::shared_ptr`. If there is a transfer of ownership and never more than one owner at a time, use `std::unique_ptr`. If neither own the resource, use a `std::weak_ptr` or a raw pointer and someone else, the owner, handles the management.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I have to use char* as after this I need to pass this vector to GPU for some computations, and GPU cant accept string it accepts char*.

Comment: Huh? Why wouldn’t it accept `some_string.c_str()`?

Comment: ... or `some_string.data()` if it needs to write to it too.

Comment: @somu_mtech *I need to pass this vector to GPU for some computations, and GPU cant accept string*   -- That's why there is a function called `c_str()`.  A string class would almost be worthless if it can't be used to interface to legacy `char *` functions.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you so much. Can you please give an example how std::shared_ptr can be used in this case. I have not used std::shared_ptr ever before.

Comment: Do not use a `shared_ptr` for this task. This is a job for `std::string`.  Using a `shared_ptr` isn't much different from using a regular pointer, and most of the differences come in the construction and destruction. `shared_ptr`s to arrays is a recent addition to the language, partly because it's something you very rarely want to do. Making something hard to do prevents people from easily stumbling into a trap. Doing it correctly can't be covered in a comment. You'll need a full-blown question. When you ask it, don't ask with an array of character, because the answer will be "Use a `string`."