# C++ rvalue shared_ptr and rvalue weak_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, weak-references

```
std::shared_ptr<std::string> test() {
  return std::make_shared<std::string>("sdsd");
}
```

```
cout << *test() << endl;
```

The above code works. Can someone please let me know where is the "sdsd" string stored. I was expecting it to error out as rvalue is a temporary object. Where is the rvalue copied to and stored in?

With weak_ptr

```
std::weak_ptr<std::string> test() {
  return std::make_shared<std::string>("sdsd");
}
```

```
  cout << *test().lock() << endl;
```

Interestingly the above code errors out. What's the difference?

Comment: yeah I am new to C++.

Comment: Thanks I am working my way through tour of C++ and https://en.cppreference.com/. Can you please help me understand where rvalue shared_ptr are stored?

Comment: I have also reduced the scope of the question to make it easy to answer.

Comment: The literal answer to your question is the semantics of a `weak_ptr` is different: it doesn't count as a reference. That's the whole point of `weak_ptr`.

Comment: In the second version, the destruction of the temporary `shared_ptr` means there are zero references to the stored string, so it is released.  In the first version there is still one reference , the return value

Comment: After returning from `test()` you get a temporary object. Normally its lifetime (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) ends after evaluating the expression. '*All temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they were created*'. Assign the result of `test()` to a variable to make lifetime more clear. In the second example the `shared_ptr` was passed to a `weak_ptr`, which does not count, when counting the number of active usages of the object and, when leaving `test()`, the usage counter goes to `0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<std::string> test() {
  return std::make_shared<std::string>("sdsd");
}
```

the constructed `shared_ptr` is returned and lives on as a temporary variable long enough to be used by the caller before going out of scope and freeing the `string` allocated by `make_shared`.

The "sdsd" `string` is stored in dynamic storage [owned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024982/what-is-ownership-of-resources-or-pointers) by the returned `shared_ptr`.

In

```
std::weak_ptr<std::string> test() {
  return std::make_shared<std::string>("sdsd");
}
```

the `shared_ptr` wasn't returned and went out of scope, taking the `string` allocated by `make_shared` with it. Since this was the only existing copy of the `shared_ptr` this leaves the returned temporary `weak_ptr` variable connected to an expired `share_ptr`. If you test the return value of `lock` you'll see it's a default-constructed `shared_ptr` holding a null pointer.

[Documentation for `std::weak_ptr::lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/lock).

The "sdsd" `string` isn't stored anywhere after `test` returns. It departed when the `shared_ptr` that owned it went out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

> The above code works. Can someone please let me know where is the "sdsd" string stored. I was expecting it to error out as rvalue is a temporary object. Where is the rvalue copied to and stored in?

The memory was allocated in the call to `make_shared`.

> Interestingly the above code errors out. What's the difference?

The difference is that the `lock` operation on a `weak_ptr` can fail if there does not exist at least one `shared_ptr` to the object. That's the purpose of `weak_ptr` -- to allow the object to be freed and access it only if it still exists.