# If we assign a dynamically allocated pointer to another pointer, what happens?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int* A = new int[2];
    A[0] = 10000;
    A[1] = 2;
    int*B = A;
    delete B;
    cout << B << A;
}
```

I found the code above, `delete B;` removes the data of array A. Can we remove allocated memory by free some another assigned pointer?

Comment: Notn really sure what you're shooting for with that last `cout` chain, but the answer to your question is yes, assuming you actually delete it correctly in the first place (that should be `delete [] B;`)

Comment: Q: Can we remove allocated memory by free some another assigned pointer?  A: Of course.  NOTES: 1) the appropriate operator is delete[], not "delete".  2) Trying to deference either A[] or B[] after the deletion is an error. 3) You're deleting the underlying heap object that's being pointed to, not the "pointer" itself.

Comment: `delete` or `delete[]` for that matter do two things: free the memory and before that: destruct the object. For `int` the destruction is trivial, nothing has to be done. But e.g. if your data represents a file, that would be closed, or if your data type internally also has dynamically allocated memory that would be freed at destruction time. Assigning (`=`) a pointer normally does a shallow copy, the new pointer just points to the same memory. If it would be a deep copy, both would have to be deleted.

Answer (score 4):

You don't delete pointers.  You delete *the thing pointed to*.

`A`, in your example isn't an array.  It is a pointer that points to the first element of an array.  When you write `int* B = A;`, you make `B` a pointer to the same memory.  At that point `A` and `B` are identical, and the array they point to can be freed via either of them.

It doesn't matter how many times you copy a pointer.  All that matters is that the thing pointed to by the pointer you pass to your deletion expression was allocated with the corresponding allocation expression (i.e. `new`/`delete`, `new[]`/`delete[]`, `malloc`/`free`, etc).

Comment: And this means that if you are not careful you can blow your program up really, really easily by `delete A;`ing while you still need `B`. Rather than being really, really careful all of the time, the modern programmer uses containers and smart pointers.

Comment: And knows about *ownership* (the single function or object owning a resource that is responsible for cleaning up the resource). *The onus of ownership* ...

Comment: [What is ownership of resources or pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024982/what-is-ownership-of-resources-or-pointers)

Answer (score 2):

> Can we remove allocated memory by free some another assigned pointer?

Yes, as long as you do it correctly i.e., using the appropriate *delete-expression*.

From [new.delete.single-12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/support.dynamic#new.delete.single-12):

> **Requires:** `ptr` shall be a null pointer or its value shall represent the address of a block of memory allocated by an earlier call to a (possibly replaced) `operator new(std​::​size_­t)` or `operator new(std​::​size_­t, std​::​align_­val_­t)` **which has not been invalidated by an intervening call to** `operator delete`.

This means that in your program, we are allowed to write:

```
delete [] B;
```

---

On the other hand `delete B;` is incorrect because we must use array-form of *delete-expression* here.