# What should be included in the destructor in C++

Tags: c++, memory, destructor

Here is two sample classes and the implementation of destructor for class `Foo`. Why is `m_barvec1` implemented as the way it is in the destructor and what does `vector<Bar *> m_barvec1` mean?

```
class Bar { 
public:
    Bar() : m_arr(new int[100]) {} 
    ~Bar();
    int m_x;
    std::list<int> m_list;
    int* m_arr; 
};

class Foo { 
public:
    Foo() : m_barvec3(new std::vector<Bar>()) {} 
    ~Foo();
    Bar m_bar; 
    std::vector<Bar *> m_barvec1; 
    std::vector<Bar> m_barvec2;
    std::vector<Bar> *m_barvec3;
};

Foo::~Foo() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m_barvec1.size(); i++) {
        delete m_barvec1[i];
    }
    delete m_barvec3;
}
```

Comment: Good reading: [What is meant by Resource Acquisition is Initialization (RAII)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii) and [What is ownership of resources or pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024982/what-is-ownership-of-resources-or-pointers)

Comment: And that leads to [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: The objects pointed to by the pointers  are being deleted in the destructor. m_barvec1 holds pointers to Bar objects.  m_barvec3 is deleted because it is a pointer to a std::vector

Comment: Slight clarification: The pointers are not deleted. The objects pointed at are deleted. You do not have to delete when you have a pointer, you have to delete when you have ownership of the pointed-at object.

Comment: `vector<Bar *> m_barvec1` is a vector of pointers to objects of type `Bar`.  When the `Foo` object is decallocated, the destructor is deleting each of the objects pointed to by that vector. Is that the correct behavior, or are those pointers owned by something else that wants to keep them allocated? This kind of dileman is why smart pointers exist.

Comment: Where did this code come from?  Did you write it yourself?

Comment: A somewhat pedantic answer to the question in the title would be that it's impossible to say, because the code doesn't show where these pointers came from. The destructor **might** be correct if all of those pointers were created with `new`.

Answer (score 1):

`m_barvec1` is a `std::vector` object holding raw pointers to `Bar` objects.  The `Foo` destructor is destroying every `Bar` object being pointed at by the `std::vector`.  A better way to handle this is to use `std::unique_ptr<Bar>` or `std::shared_ptr<Bar>` instead of `Bar*` for the `std::vector`'s element type, let `std::unique_ptr`/`std::shared_ptr` destroy the `Bar` objects automatically.

`m_barvec2` is a `std::vector` object holding `Bar` objects.  The `std::vector`'s destructor will handle destroying the `Bar` objects, so there is no user code needed in `Foo`'s destructor to handle this.

`m_barvec3` is a pointer to a `std::vector` object that holds `Bar` objects.  The `Foo` destructor is destroying the `std::vector` being pointed at, which in turn will destroy the `Bar` objects it holds. A better way to handle this is to use `std::unique_ptr<std::vector<Bar>>` instead of `std::vector<Bar>*` for the pointer, let `std::unique_ptr` destroy the `std::vector` automatically.

Using smart pointers for `m_barvec1` and `m_barvec3` would allow `Foo`'s destructor to then be removed completely.

Comment: Addendum: It is very likely that `~Bar` will have to `delete[] m_arr;`

Comment: @user4581301 True, though the question is about `~Foo`, not `~Bar`.