# Why do I get an error when I overload the << on the object returned by the + operator overloaded function

Tags: c++, overloading, return-value

```
class String
{
    char* array;
public:
    String(const char* s)
    {
        array = new char[strlen(s) + 1]{ '\0' };
        strcpy(array, s);
    }
    ~String()
    {
        if (array)
        {
            delete[]array;
        }
    }
    String operator+ (const char* p)   //返回对象
    {
        String temp(p);
        char* tempStr = temp.array;
        temp.array = new char[strlen(array) + strlen(tempStr) + 1]{ '\0' };
        strcpy(temp.array, array);
        strcat(temp.array, p);
        delete[]tempStr;
        return temp;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, String& x);   // <<函数重载只能定义成友元
};

ostream& operator << (ostream& output, String& x)  //对<<重载的方式
{
    output << x.array;
    return output;
}

int main()
{
    String string1("mystring");
    cout << string1 + "ab" << endl;
    cout << string1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is my first time asking a question here, so please forgive me if there are any bad descriptions :)

Back to the point ,I have overloaded `+` and `<<` operators,so I want to get the output "`mystringab`" by `cout<<string1+"ab"<<endl`，but the output is garbled.

I think there may be a problem with the `+` operator overloaded function,can someone please tell me where is the problem？

And if I want to get the correct result, how should I rewrite the overloaded function?

Comment: Make the second parameter of `operator<<` a `const String&`.

Comment: Thanks, but I just tried it and it still seems to output garbled characters :(

Comment: See my answer below and this [working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/2XX1CNnxD). Also don't forget to make sure that you don't have any undefined behavior in your program.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :)   I am learning object-oriented programming so I am not very clear about some mechanisms

Comment: I'll take a closer look later

Comment: `delete[]tempStr;` right before `return temp;` frees the buffer [owned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024982/what-is-ownership-of-resources-or-pointers) by temp. This is fatal.

Comment: `String` does not observe [the rule of three or friends](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). This means it cannot be copied safely. Passing or returning by value will make copies. `String operator+ (const char* p)` returns by value, makes a copy and thus will be fatal.

Comment: Some good reading: [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: how should I rewrite the overloaded function by value

Comment: Tactical note: If you add a book-keeping variable to track the length of the string, you can save yourself the costs of calling `strlen` over and over.

Comment: You need to return by value from `operator+`, this means you must make `String` copyable (or rewrite to ensure elision, but a copyable class is much more useful than one that will fail if copied). Read the posted link about [the Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: I suggest asking a second question that specifically deals with improving `operator+` because Stack Overflow is at it's best when it deals with one problem per question. There are very important suggestions in the posted link [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/) that may eliminate the need for this question, though.

Comment: I thought about it for a few hours and finally I know where I went wrong. When `temp` is returned, the copy constructor written by the compiler itself will be called to make a `shallow copy`, thereby creating an anonymous object, the `char *array`  of this anonymous object and `temp.array` point to the same address, so when the function ends and `temp` is destructed, the `char *array` of the anonymous object is also deleted, so garbled characters will be output. The solution is to define a copy constructor by yourself to make a deep copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the second parameter to overloaded `operator<<` cannot be bound to an `String` rvalue since the second parameter is an *lvalue reference to a non-const `String`*.

> how should I rewrite the overloaded function?

You need to make the second parameter to overloaded `operator<<` a `const String&` so that it can work with the second argument `"ab"` as well, as shown below:

```
//---------------------------------------- vvvvv------------>low-level const added here
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output,const String& x);
```

Similarly do the same in the definition:

```
//----------------------------------- vvvvv------------>low-level const added here
ostream& operator << (ostream& output,const String& x) 
{
    output << x.array;
    return output;
}
```

Also, make sure that your program don't have any undefined behavior. For example, by making sure that you use `delete` or `delete[]` only when it is safe to do so(that data to which the pointer points is no longer needed). You can use tools such as valgrind to detect some basic problems.