# What is the best way to access elements of a class member container from outside that class in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, containers

In the following example, using pointers has caused me some complications that I'd like to avoid. So I'm wondering that the correct way of dealing with this situation would be.

So I have a struct called `Cars`. It's a container to hold objects of class `Car`. Specifically, The `Cars` class has a member variable that stores all of the `Car` objects in a vector. An instantiation of Cars exists in the scope of a simulation that needs to access a variable number of Car objects within Cars.

To describe my issue here is an example sim of cars honking. While I know the following example can be improved in many obvious ways to better simulate cars honking, keep in mind this example's purpose is to show the structure of a much more complicated simulation whose structure I cannot broadly alter very too much.

```
struct Car {
   public:
       std::string id_;
       std::string make_;
       Car(const std::string& id, const std::string make) : id_(id) make_(make) {}
       void honk(){
          std::cout<<"Car "<<id_<<" honked!"<<std::endl;
       };
};

class Cars {
private:
    std::vector<Car> garage;

public:
    void addCar(const Car& car) {
        cars.push_back(car);
    }

    // Returns reference to element in garage vector
    Car& get_car_by_id(const std::string id){
        for (Car& car: garage) {
            if (car.id_ == id) return car;
        }
    }

    // Returns a vector of pointers to elements in garage vector
    vector<std::unique_ptr<Car>> get_cars_by_make(const std::string &make) {
        vector<std::unique_ptr<Car>> subset;
        for (Car& car: garage) {
            if (car.make == make) {
                subset.push_back(std::make_unique<Car>(car));
            }
        }
        return subset;
    }
};
```

In the following small simulation we use the two different getter methods to access Car objects: via a single reference to access an individual object, and then a vector of smart pointers to access a variable number of objects based on some condition that can change throughout the simulation. The latter is the crux of my issue.

```
int main() {
    Cars fleet;

    fleet.addCar(Car("1", "Toyota"));
    fleet.addCar(Car("2", "Toyota"));
    fleet.addCar(Car("3", "Tesla"));

    // Honk horn for car 3
    Car& car fleet.get_car_by_id("3");
    car.honk();

    // Honk all of the Toyota's horns
    vector<std::unique_ptr<Car>> cars = garage.get_by_make("Toyota");
    for (const auto car : cars) {
        car.honk();
    }
}
```

My question is this: Is there a better way to provide access to these Car objects? I've been trying to avoid pointers as much as possible but I feel like they're the only thing that makes sense. Short of providing the index values of the objects instead of pointers (which sounds disgusting), I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Return a `std::span<Car>` (But then caller can only use it locally!)

Comment: One note, not necessarily solving your question: what does `get_car_by_id` return if it doesn't find a matching car?

Comment: Side note.  You really don't need the `Cars` class since it's just a glorified map between strings and instances of Car.  It can simply be `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Car>>`

Comment: `for (const auto car : cars) {` - should be `for (const auto& car : cars) {` - so you don't copy every car just to honk it.

Comment: @Selbie philosphical question (to show my thought processes), does the garage strictly speaking own the car? But I can also see it extending the lifetime of the car (I am always careful with shared_ptr somehow, it is usually my last choice, something with circular dependencies in big projects...)

Comment: Don't fear the pointer. The problem usually isn't with the pointer, but with what's been pointed at and how that pointed-at object is being managed. The vast majority of the time you want to manage a dynamically allocated object with a container or smart pointer and pass it around to mere users as a raw pointer. In modern C++, raw pointer should mean "I do not [own](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49024982/4581301) the pointed-at object. I just get to use it temporarily."

Comment: Your `get_car_by_id` and `get_cars_by_make` are flawed in that they do not return anything when cars are not found.  Thus your code will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `getc_cars_by_make` _never_ returns anything as it stands.

Comment: @Chris Yes, `get_cars_by_make` makes matters worse by not returning anything.

Comment: Fixed the lack of a return statement in `get_cars_by_make`

Comment: @Curiousengineer You still need to fix `get_car_by_id` if no car is found.

Answer (score 3):

`get_cars_by_make()` does not return a vector of pointers to cars in the garage.  It returns a vector of unique pointers to new cars that were copy-constructed from the cars in the garage.

If you want to return pointers to the cars already in the garage, return `vector<Car*>` instead of `vector<unique_ptr<Car>>`.

Edit:  I realize that this is a minimal example, but if `get_cars_by_make()` doesn't do anything but a linear search, the method doesn't do anything a client couldn't do for itself if it could see the vector iterators.  If you exported those iterators (ideally as a range, but possibly with begin/end methods or even returning a reference to the vector), then the client could find by make without having to allocate a vector to hold the results.

Comment: Actually, the `get_cars_by_make` doesn't return anything, which is wrong.

Comment: So is the solution to never get into a situation where you need to return pointers to vector elements?

Comment: If you're going to do the search inside Cars, then you need to return some way of referencing the individual Cars in your result, and Car* is the simplest and cleanest way to do it.  If you returned the garage as a range, however, the client could do the search itself, and you wouldn't have to allocate a container to hold the results, which would be more efficient and wouldn't involve pointers.

Comment: @Curiousengineer The best way is to return a `std::span<Car>` if you use C++20. Vectors implicitly convert to spans. And for searching inside that span just do std::find/_if

Answer (score 0):

Building off of user1806566's answer, I think there's some confusion around the difference between a vector of unique_ptr's and a vector of * pointers. This is something I struggled to understand early on. 'unique_ptr' is allocating memory for new objects on the heap, which in many cases like this is unnecessary. A pointer using * but without any sort of smart pointer or 'new' keyword acts as a reference to an existing object on the stack. This is the more simple approach, and avoids unnecessary complication that often comes with using the heap. I recommend doing some reading on the differences between the stack and the heap.

Answer (score 0):

I would make Cars simply a database of shared_ptr using `std::map` set `std::set` to manage the collections (or the unordered version). That way, we can keep the **same car** in different collection tables (id to car, make to list of cars, etc...).  Then we don't make redundant copies of a Car. And we can share the pointer to Car rather freely without worry of a dangling pointer if the "fleet" destructs while someone else is driving the car.

The use of `auto` keyword in this example is not lost on me. :)

```
class Cars {

private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Car>> garage;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Car>> idToCarTable;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<Car>>> makeToCarsTable;

public:
    void addCar(const Car& car) {
        auto spCar = std::make_shared<Car>(car);
        garage.push_back(spCar);
        idToCarTable[spCar->id_] = spCar;
        makeToCarsTable[car.make_].insert(spCar);
    }

    std::shared_ptr<Car> get_car_by_id(const std::string& id) {
        auto itor = idToCarTable.find(id);
        if (itor != idToCarTable.end()) {
            return itor->second;
        }
        return std::shared_ptr<Car>(); // null
    }

    std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<Car>> get_cars_by_make(const std::string& make) {
        std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<Car>> resultSet;
        auto itor = makeToCarsTable.find(make);
        if (itor != makeToCarsTable.end()) {
            // make a copy of the set
            resultSet = itor->second;
        }
        return resultSet;
    }
};
```

Then your main is mostly what you have:

```
int main() {
    Cars fleet;

    fleet.addCar(Car("1", "Toyota"));
    fleet.addCar(Car("2", "Toyota"));
    fleet.addCar(Car("3", "Tesla"));

    // Honk horn for car 3
    auto car3 = fleet.get_car_by_id("3");
    if (car3 != nullptr) {
        car3->honk();
    }

    // Honk all of the Toyota's horns
    auto toyotas = fleet.get_cars_by_make("Toyota");
    for (const auto& toyota : toyotas) {
        toyota->honk();
    }
}
```