# Dummy/Sentinel Node Memory C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* test(ListNode* list) {
        ListNode dummy;
        ListNode* cur = &dummy;
        cur->next = list;
        return dummy.next;
    }
};
```

Since I created the dummy object within the function "test", once I return from this function the dummy object should be destroyed as it is out of scope. If I defined a proper destructor for ListNode to also delete the next ListNode pointer, such as

```
~ListNode() {
  delete next;
}
```

then once the dummy node is destroyed, it should call the destructor of its member variables, thus deleting the next pointer and so on, and so this return should be invalid? Or is it not the case, and only dummy object is deleted, and dummy.next remains on the heap?

I'm unsure as I've been using dummy nodes like such on Leetcode where it works, but thinking about it, it might be that ListNode uses a default destructor which doesn't delete the next pointer, and if I did have an explicit destructor, then this would result in a problem.

Comment: If `ListNode` has a destructor you show, then indeed setting up `dummy` variable has the effect you describe - `test` would wipe out the whole list that `list` points to. If `ListNode` doesn't have such a destructor, then `test` is equivalent to `return list;` - the dance around `dummy` is a no-op.

Comment: Unrelated: I don't recommend list nodes that can delete their linked nodes. It turns the destruction into a potentially stack-smashing recursion, forcing you to keep the lists short. If you can make short-enough guarantees, consider making the [ownershiip](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49024982/4581301) obvious with `std::unique_ptr` and let [the Rule of Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) take care of the destructor. Also easily inhibits accidental copies of the node without any extra effort, and that's worth it's weight in electrons.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the pointer in the destructor will indeed cause a cascading construction.

It makes the class ListNode entirely unusable on the stack (which may be what you want), and will cascade deletion of all the ListNode's.

```
 ~ListNode()
 {
      delete next;
 }
```

Will cause the returned value to be deleted.  Which is useless.  You probably want a different design.
By default standard objects (int, double, float and all pointers) won't be destructed automatically by the default destructor.