# C++: is it undefined behaviour to create with a bitwise copy of an object using a C-style cast to char[] (and back)?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

I find this question hard to precisely phrase. I have come across a bizarre situation in a large project of mine where I need to work with lambdas that capture by value. In short, I have something like the following (and variations thereof):

```
struct my_data_t
{
    std::vector<double> d_data;
    std::vector<int>    i_data;
};
```

The way I end up operating on these data structures is through lambdas. Let's say I have a lambda that sets the i-th element based on a `std::pair`:

```
const auto my_lam = [&](const int i, const std::pair<double, int>& elem)
{
    data.d_data[i] = elem.first;
    data.i_data[i] = elem.second;
};
```

I can clearly then just do the following:

```
my_data_t data{{1.0, 1.3, 1.9, 9.3}, {1, 4, 3, 5}};

const auto my_lam = [&](const int i, const std::pair<double, int> elem)
{
    data.d_data[i] = elem.first;
    data.i_data[i] = elem.second;
};

my_lam(1, {100.3, 15});
```

This works fine, and when I print the contents of the vectors, I see the values I set. However, for hardware reasons that are too complicated/involved to get into here, I am **strictly** forbidden from capturing `data` by reference. This is an absolute limit.

It goes without saying that

```
my_data_t data{{1.0, 1.3, 1.9, 9.3}, {1, 4, 3, 5}};

auto my_lam = [=](const int i, const std::pair<double, int> elem) mutable
{
    data.d_data[i] = elem.first;
    data.i_data[i] = elem.second;
};

my_lam(1, {100.3, 15});
```

does not work for me for obvious reasons.

The current solution in my codebase is a "view-like" implementation, e.g.

```
template <typename data_t> struct vec_image_t
{
    data_t* raw;
    std::size_t c_size;
    // indexing operators, etc
};
```

and then modifying `my_data_t` to be something like

```
template <template <typename> container_t = std::vector> struct my_data_t
{
    container_t<double> d_data;
    container_t<int>    i_data;
};
```

This works well, but suffers the issue that I need to write an awful lot of boilerplate code to convert a `my_data_t<std::vector>` to a `my_data_t<vec_image_t>`, meaning this approach does not scale well (I have many variations of `my_data_t`). It is also a complete headache when `const` comes into the mix.

I tried to dream up some solutions to this problem when I realized that all I really need is a `my_data_t` (as shown in the first implementation without the `template template`) whose copy constructor and destructor are never called. I looked to c++20's `bit_cast` for this and it seems to be what I want, but it requires that the cast type be trivially copyable, and in the case of e.g. `std::vector`, this is not satisfied.

I came up with my own cast, much like `bit_cast`, just without the trival requirement:

```
template <typename thing_t>
requires(sizeof(thing_t) == sizeof(image_t<thing_t>))
image_t<thing_t> make_image(thing_t& thing)
{
    image_t<thing_t> output;
    std::memcpy(&output.raw[0], &thing, output.cpy_size);
    return output;
}
```

where `image_t<thing_t>` looks like

```
template <typename thing_t> struct image_t
{
    constexpr static std::size_t cpy_size = sizeof(thing_t);
    char raw[cpy_size];
    
    thing_t* operator -> ()
    {
        return (thing_t*)(&raw[0]);
    }
    
    thing_t& operator * ()
    {
        return *(thing_t*)(&raw[0]);
    }
     // and const versions...
};
```

This works perfectly for my small problem:

```
my_data_t data{{1.0, 1.3, 1.9, 9.3}, {1, 4, 3, 5}};
auto d_img = make_image(data);
auto my_lam = [=](const int i, const std::pair<double, int> elem) mutable
{
    d_img->d_data[i] = elem.first;
    d_img->i_data[i] = elem.second;
};

my_lam(1, {100.3, 15});
```

For my larger codebase, this solution would allow me to strip an awful lot of complexity out and make my users' lives easier. It also has the advantage that the `image_t<thing_t>` acts an awful lot like `thing_t*`, which fits with the semantics of use. I understand that storing `image_t<thing_t>` is dangerous, but I see no further danger than storing iterators.

*My question is whether or not this is undefined behaviour.* I worry that this is UB for obvious reasons, but according to the [standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing), under "Type aliasing":

> Whenever an attempt is made to read or modify the stored value of an object of type DynamicType through a glvalue of type AliasedType, the behavior is undefined unless one of the following is true:
>
> - ...
> - AliasedType is ... char ...: this permits examination of the object representation of any object as an array of bytes.

This appears to absolve my `make_image` cast of any UB. Is this the case?

Comment: *I am strictly forbidden from capturing data by reference*  Capture a pointer to the data, rather than a reference of the data.

Comment: @Eljay Perhaps I should have mentioned, but the reason I can't capture by reference is that the lambda is executed in a different memory space, so capturing a pointer by value is equally as invalid.

Comment: Converting from any object to a `char` array is always legal. Converting a `char` array to an object is legal so long as the `char` array contains a valid object of the same type. Watch out for stuff like data alignment and endian, but if you convert to char an then convert back with no other monkey work between the two conversions, that's not going to be a problem. If you stream the characters  to some other program, though...

Comment: You can't copy a class with vectors in it using `memcpy`. Same rules as `bit_cast`. It will create a mess of UB.

Comment: Handy reading: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable

Comment: If you bit-wise copy a `vector` you copy the pointers in the vector, not the data buffers that were pointed at. This means you now have two objects claiming to be `vector` instances that both point at the same places and believe they are the sole [owner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49024982/4581301) of the same resources. If nothing like a `vector` resize horribly breaks the program first, both `vector`s will try to release the same buffer for usually fatal results. To be honest, you pray the results are fatal because the alternatives are worse.

Comment: @user4581301 The bit-wise copy of the pointers is precisely the behaviour that I am after. The face that the image stores the "vector" as a char array means that no instance of ~vector is ever called. I am well aware of RAII and rule-of-3.

Comment: @doug Can you give an example of UB here? Keep in mind that `image<T>` does not own a `T`, so creating one never calls `~T()`. Regarding sizing, I am not actually using `std::vector` so the issue of calling `resize()` is not relevant here.

Comment: A vector is (basically) a smart pointer to an array of objects.  If you can't use a pointer because it's executed in a different memory space, you'll have the same problem with a vector.

Comment: @Eljay I use an allocator that allocates in the appropriate memory space.

Comment: You've been playing around with views, why not a simple class that's not copying anything and just holding non-owning pointers to the `vector`'s data buffers? If the memory is 100% safe and addressable, I don't see why you need anything more complicated than a struct with two pointers in it that's captured by value where the value is merely two addresses.

Comment: @user4581301 I can do that just fine, but it scales horribly when I start having data structures composed of vectors. If I have, say, 30 different classes, each of which own any number of vectors (or are composed of other classes that also own vectors), I don't want to implement `to_view` or whatever in each of them. My codebase implements this at the moment, and it accounts for a lot of complexity.

Comment: Alright. What you've got will be UB, but UB that you've proved manifests the way you need it to manifest on your target systems might as well be legal. Just be sure to re-prove when porting or updating the build tools.

Comment: While this may well work with current implementations of `vector` where pointers are stored that are not self object referential, it would not work for instance on `std::string` due to SSO. If some clever library creator decided to do SVO (short vector optimization)  along similar lines to SSO, it would certainly fail. This is one of those boundary issues where you have to make assumptions that are likely valid but smelly. If you do so I highly recommend you put this stuff in a single file where you put anything that might be invalid in the future and strongly point it out in the documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I looked to c++20's bit_cast for this and it seems to be what I want, but it requires that the cast type be trivially copyable, and in the case of e.g. std::vector, this is not satisfied.

This restriction exists because copying the object representation (whether by `bit_cast` or `memcpy`) between objects of any other type has undefined behavior.

So yes, UB.

Comment: *copying the object representation (whether by bit_cast or memcpy) between objects of any other type has undefined behavior* This seems to be false based on the quote from the standard I provided: `Whenever an attempt is made to read or modify the stored value of an object of type DynamicType through a glvalue of type AliasedType, the behavior is undefined unless one of the following is true: ... `. Can you explain how this is still UB based on this clause?

Comment: @wvn That's completely irrelevant. You are not trying to read or modify the value of an object through a glvalue to that object. You are instead copying object representations. It is UB by omission, because the standard specifies the behavior of objects when their object representaitons are copied only for trivially-copyable types. See https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#types.general-2.