# Should I pass a vector inside a class to a member function of that class or is it ok to just access it?

Tags: c++

I was wondering if I should pass the `fishes` `vector` into the `fishExists` function, or if I should pass the `fish` instead of the `fishId` to the `fishExists` function

```cpp
class Aquarium {
    std::vector<Fish*> fishes;

public:
    bool addFish(Fish* fish);

    bool fishExists(unsigned int fishId);
};


bool Aquarium::addFish(Fish *fish) {
    if(fishExists(fish->getId())) {
        return false;
    }

    fish->setAquarium(this);
    fishes.push_back(fish);

    return true;
}

bool Aquarium::fishExists(unsigned int fishId) {
    auto it = std::find_if(fishes.begin(), fishes.end(), [fishId](const Fish* fish) {
        return fish->getId() == fishId;
    });

    return it != fishes.end();
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't pass the vector, there is no need to since member functions have direct access to all members of the class.

Comment: I'd use a `std::unordered_map<int,Fish>` to map fish id's to fishes. Then you don't even need find_if and just can uses Fishes.at(fish->id)

Comment: To answer the second question: I'd pass a `Fish` (and receive it by reference) to `fishExists` instead of `fishId`.

Comment: Tactical note: Soon you are going to reach a decision gate where you absolutely must have [ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49024982/4581301) of the `Fishes` fully defined. If you do not, you'll have a memory management nightmare on your hands. I recommend looking at `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Fish>>` fairly early.

Comment: Non static Member functions can access their non static data members without them passed as parameter. This is explained in any [beginner c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Is it *correct* for any other `std::vector<Fish *>` to be passed to `fishExists`, or should it *always* be the member `fishes`?

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/169472/165353

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to pass the `fishes` vector to the `bool fishExists(unsigned int fishId);` function as they are both in the same class.

**Member functions can access other members directly**

- in this case: your `fishExists()` function can access your `fishes` vector because they are in the same class `Aquarium`.

Answer (score 0):

As fishes is a private member variable, it is accessible to all member function of the same class.
Therefore there is no need to pass it as an argument.
Perhaps it would be better to explicitly specify that fishes is the private member variable:

```
class Aquarium {
private:
    std::vector<Fish*> fishes;

public:
    bool addFish(Fish* fish);

    bool fishExists(unsigned int fishId);
};
```

If you have a derived class:

```
class DerivedAquarium : public Aquarium{

public:
    bool derivedFishExists(unsigned int fishId, const std::vector<Fish*> &fishes);
};
```

In that case you would have to pass the fishes vector to the derived member function (perhaps by adding getFishes() function in your base class).
So, member functions of your base class can access all the member variables (even private).
However member function of the derived class can not access private members of its base class. The only way to do that is to use friend declaration.

Comment: Member functions of derived classes can access protected member variables of the base class. Otherwise derivedFishExists could call itself fishExists from the base class to delegate some functionality. If one passes the fishes vector as parameter, the function should either be a static member function or a free function. It does not make sense (and is confusing and error-prone) to call a non-static member function with a separate fishes parameter.